# Is "master-slave" polite name for software library?

Tags: politeness

I am going to write an opensource software library for web sites developers.

With help of this library, web application opened in several tabs will be able to hold connection to server from one "master" tab, and the rest of tabs will be "slaves" without direct connection to web server.

So, is "master-slave.js" good name for  the library? For developers this name describes the functionality of the library and is practical.

But maybe it is too offensive and I need to change it to "primary-secondary" or something else.
Thanks!

Comment: Neither of your suggested names sounds like a good idea due to not being searchable.

Comment: Do libraries get worried about this sort of thing?

Comment: Master/slave used to be quite common nomenclature, but I do not recall seeing it in any new technology for the past 10 years, at least.  It is probably best avoided.

Comment: I don't think its is offensive, but as a name for a library, it seems too generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't find it a problem, but many do.

> The computer term "master/slave," which was banned as racially offensive by a Los Angeles County purchasing department, was named the most politically incorrect term of the year. 
>   (-- Reuters, December 2, 2004 *via* [seattlepi.com](http://www.seattlepi.com/national/article/Master-slave-named-most-politically-incorrect-1161133.php))

The [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)) entry for **Master/Slave Technology** has a lot of information on this terminology in the hardware field, and elsewhere, along with some historical and political reactions, and attempts to find less potentially offensive alternatives.

For software applications, it mentions **'leader/follower'** and **'primary/replica'**; these may or may not be appropriate for your circumstances but should give you some ideas.

Comment: +1 for primary/replica. (Also: *standby*.)